# Managing Focus in an Autosuggestion Field in SwiftUI in a MacOS App

Tags: macos, swiftui, focus

I want to build an "autosuggestion field" in SwiftUI in a MacOS App.
My first attempts work quite OK.
The problem I face is managing the focus, to enable smooth keyboard (only) handling.

If the users has entered more than 1 char in the textfield, a list with suggestions is displayed. At the moment the user can choose one with the mouse.
What I want is, that the user can still edit the textfield, navigate in the textfield with Cursor-Left and Cursor-Right (which is the case) and **additionally navigate** the list with *Cursor-Up* and *Cursor-Down* and **select an entry** with e.g. *Space* or *Enter*.

```
struct TestSearchField2: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      SearchField2()
    } .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
  }
}

enum SuggestionListStatus {
  case off
  case on
  case accepted
}

struct SearchField2: View {
  let allSuggestions =  ["michael Schneider","thomas mueller","joachim Oster","Dennis mueller","Michael Carter","frank 1","frank 2","frank 3","frank 4","frank 5"]
  @State var input = ""
  @State var showList : SuggestionListStatus = .off
  @State var selected = ""

  var body: some View {
    TextField("input Data", text: $input)
    .cornerRadius(5.0)
      .overlay(SuggestionList2(suggestionListStatus: $showList, selected: $input, suggestions: allSuggestions.filter {$0.contains(input)}))
    .onChange(of: input, perform: { value in
      if showList == .accepted {
        showList = .off}
      else if input.count >= 2 {
        print(
        allSuggestions.filter {$0.contains(input)})
        showList = .on
      } else {
        showList = .off
      }
    })
  }
}


struct SuggestionList2: View {
  @Binding var suggestionListStatus : SuggestionListStatus
  @Binding var selected : String
  @State var selection : String? = "Michael"
  var suggestions : [String] 


  var body: some View {
    if suggestionListStatus == .on {
      VStack{
        List(suggestions, id: \.self, selection: $selection){ s in
          Text(s).onTapGesture {
            print("Pressed; \(s)")
            selected = s
            suggestionListStatus = .accepted
          }
        }
        Text("Debug setected: \(selection ?? "nothing selected")").font(.footnote)
    }
    .frame(width: 200, height: 150, alignment: .leading)
    .offset(x: 0, y: 100)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrapped a NSTextField in NSViewRepresentable and used the NSTextFieldDelegate. You can find my example of GitHub.

[SuggestionsDemo Project on GitHub](https://github.com/smic/SuggestionsDemo)

Comment: perfect solution! tnx, under witch license did you publish the demo?

Comment: Public domain. I added a license file.

Comment: Thanks @StephanMichels! Been looking for something like this for quite some time. I owe you big time. However, i noticed it creates too many window instances with some of them positioned at the bottom left hand of the screen. I could try to fix this myself but if you have any pointers that could be helfpul.